# React Native Syntax Error: Unexpected Token, expected }

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

An error `Unexpected token, expected }` suddenly appeared without a clear cause.

[image]

Line 136:7 is right where it says master: {

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 master: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
 }
});
```

It was working fine before. I have tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

No changes from either of those.

Answer (score 8):

This error was due to a missing `</>` in my render method.

Comment: can you explain... i'm having the same issue when I add a style... but if i add inline styles, then its ok.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the error was

> unexpected token , expected ","

.
the reason was in the stylesheet, used = in place of :

`color = colors.white` instead of `color: colors.white`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `ComponentDidUpdate` was after the `render()` method.